# Running pyqt with root privilege?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I am trying to run `pyqt` file with `sudo` but the GUI doesn't run when running as root. It gives me this error:

```
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x142
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x3000010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3000011
```

So, is there a way to run it with root privileges?

Comment: Try `xhost +` in the terminal and then `xhost -` when you are finished. Your question is not really about progamming BTW.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin the same .. it dosn't work!
my question is about making a program work, it is relevant some how i guess! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem running QT from a Docker container.

Try with this (it was the solution for me):

```
echo "export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

echo "export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" >> $HOME/.bashrc

it work for my. thnks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I running **`OpenCV`** in `Ubuntu 18.04`. I have solved using the below command

```
export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1` followed by your command.

for example, to run a python script:

```
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 python example.py
```